# Jest --findRelatedTests flag not finding related test

Tags: javascript, jestjs, yarnpkg

Running the CLI command `yarn run jest --findRelatedTests src/components/Banner.js` in my environment doesn't run the corresponding test `Banner.test.js` located in the `__tests__` folder in the same directory. Why would this happen? Output of the command:

```
Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
No files found in...
...
Pattern: src/components/Banner.js - 0 matches
```

Jest config also doesn't have any `rootDir` or `roots` specified which I presume could affect it.

For reference, the directory structure is:

```
src/components
    __tests__
        Banner.test.js
    Banner.js
```

yarn run jest works as expected on all tests.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you ever figure it out?